# How to record an action to center the content of a layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

For example, there are 2 layers:

- an iPhone mockup
- an app icon upper left of the mockup screen

When I want to export the app icon as a .png file, now I:

- copy the icon layer to a new PSD
- use the mouse to drag the icon to center
- change canvas to 57 x 57
- further arrange the icon position
- export

Is there a way to quickly clone a layer and center it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action should:

- Turn off all other layers (Alt/Opt-click on the layer eyeball)
- Select All (Cmd/Ctl-A)
- Copy Merged (Cmd/Ctl-Shift-C)
- Turn other layers back on (Alt/Opt-click again)
- Create a new document
- Paste
- Select All
- Center Vertically and Center Horizontally (use the icons in the control bar)
- Canvas Size to 54x54 absolute
- Deselect

This will then work for any layer you have targeted in the Layers Panel.